# wxpython frame crashes on closing in 64 bit version of python 2.7 but is fine in 32 bit

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am building a GUI application to run a database using wxpython 3 with python 2.7. When I run the application with 32bit python it runs without a problem. However, when I looked to run the same code in 64bit it works well but the application always crashes out during the closing a frame. This occurs both where I have intercepted the close event or not.

Is there something special about the 64 bit version that needs to be done to avoid the instability?

Comment: crashes I've encountered with wx usually have to do with ImageLists, hard to tell whats causing yours without seeing it though

Comment: No. This sounds like something isn't getting closed correctly and the 32-bit vs 64-bit part of it is a red herring. My guess is that there are threads involved, children frames that aren't closed or some other simple issue